# Metallic hydrogen production

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, hydrogen

Why is there such a big deal made about metallic hydrogen if it can't be made industrially? I mean, it's very hard to produce in a lab, and the samples produced are of very small quantity, so why are many researchers and papers making such a big deal about its use when it would be impossible/impractical to produce on an industrial scale? Is there something I'm missing here and is it possible to produce economically on an industrial scale? And if so, how would it be done?

Comment: Less than 200 years ago aluminum was a rare exotic metal worth more than its weight in gold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll address your questions individually.

**Why is metallic hydrogen a big deal?** Because it demonstrates very exotic properties compared to any other material we know of.

**What is the point if we can't make a lot of it?** The same could be said about high purity silicon, until we figured out how to make a lot of it in the 50s. Now you find it in every digital device on the planet. It is the bedrock of the digital revolution.

**Can it be made economically?** Not that we know of.

**How would we do it?** Ask me again in a decade or a century, maybe someone will have figured it out by then.

Comment: so basically, we just haven't figured it out yet?

Comment: Pretty much, also it is impossible to put a time horizon on these types of things. Historically it has taken decades or sometimes even centuries to figure out the manufacturing of new materials. However that doesn't mean we shouldn't try, whenever we succeeded it generally meant radical improvements in prosperity for all of mankind.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer.